# MiKTeX where do I specify command line options?

Tags: luatex, miktex

I'm using MiKTeX 2.9 and I want to specify the command line option --shell-escape. The reason for this is that I'm trying to use an eps file and I get the error

> xxx-eps-converted-to.pdf' not found.

I read that this command line option can fix the problem, but where exactly do I specify it? I'm typesetting with LuaLaTeX using TeXworks as the editor.

EDIT: added editor.

Comment: Are you running LuaLaTeX from the command line or using an editor, and if so which one?

Comment: @JosephWright TeXworks, added it to my question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With TeXworks, go to the main menu: Edit / Preferences, choose the Typesetting tab, choose your engine, click the Edit button, add `--enable-write18` such as here:

[image: Screenshot from TeXworks]

This screenshot was originally posted by Thorsten in the [LaTeX-Community forum](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=21063&start=10#p69960). In the picture it's for pdfLaTeX, just edit the engine of your choice, i.e. LuaLaTeX.

Use the very same place if you would like to add `--shell-escape` instead. However, `--shell-escape` is used in TeX Live, `--enable-write18` in MiKTeX.

Comment: In addition: `--enable-write18` is the original switch for MiKTeX, but `--shell-escape` works, too.

Answer (score 2):

Specify the switch after invoking LuaLaTeX. As an example, `lualatex --shell-escape luatex.tex`. This assumes you’re invoking LuaLaTeX from a command line.